# Prevent href from autocomplete with website address

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where users must fill it with their facebook and instagram links. When users don't type their whole address (for example: `https://www.facebook.com/userfacebook"`) and just fill it with `facebook.com/userfacebook`, when this data comes from DB to display users information on an facebook image icon link, `href` is auto completing it with my website address + what users have filled previously:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/dashboard/home/facebook.com/userfacebook`

If users fill the form with the whole facebook link (`https://www.facebook.com/userfacebook`) this problem doesn't happen. The image icon link is filled with the right facebook path.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row mt-20">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label for="facebook">Facebook profile</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="facebook" id="facebook" placeholder="Ex: https://wwww.facebook.com/yourname" />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                *Required
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row mt-20">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label for="instagram">Instagram profile</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="instagram" id="instagram" placeholder="Ex: https://wwww.instagram.com/yourname" />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                *Required
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
axios.post("https://mywebsite.com/backend/get.php", {
        token: token,
    })
    .then((response) => {

        if (response.data != "Error getting data") {

            loading.innerHTML = "";
            response.data.forEach((res) => {
                userInfos.innerHTML +=
                    /* html */
                    `<div class="share-container">
                         <a href="${res.facebook}" target="_blank">
                             <img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/facebook-purple.png" alt="share-fb">
                         </a>
                         <a href="${res.instagram}" target="_blank">
                             <img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/instagram-purple.png" alt="share-ig">
                         </a>
                     </div>`;
            });
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to prevent this without replacing strings or something like that?

Comment: The URLs probably aren't being autocompleted. Browsers have to interpret incomplete URLS as relative, so they're appended to the current domain.

Comment: _“Is there a way to prevent this without replacing strings”_ - no, there is not. This is simply how URLs work. If you specify a relative URL (and that’s what `facebook.com/userfacebook` without any protocol is), then it will get expanded to an absolute one, by using the current document’s base URL.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for explanations! I think I'm going to specify in `placeholder` to fill with usernames only and implement some rules to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try autocomplete attribute but with random string as a value

```
<input class="form-control" autocomplete="randomstringhere" type="text" name="facebook" id="facebook" placeholder="Ex: https://wwww.facebook.com/yourname" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest only asking the users for the usernames and then you can prepend the rest of the url when processing their input.  You could also implement regex to ensure they don't give you a full url (a string that starts with https:// or a string that contains /, for instance).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27746068)

Comment: This is an alternative solution that would solve the problem.  Why is this not considered an answer?

Comment: Stating that there could be an alternative solution is missing the point. I think there is a mismatch between the specific question and your outline that lists the general, related concepts but does not provide enough explanations to help OP or other readers formulate an actual solution. General suggestions can be made in the comment. Granted, this is a judgement call. Others may disagree. Or perhaps you can tell me and OP how your existing writing already tie things together.